# How to intercept timezone of a DateTime object and convert it to another timezone (Ruby/Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, datetime, timezone

I have an application that receives emails on behalf of various users, and these users inboxes (fetched through IMAP with the `Mail` gem) have various timezones. E.g.:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.12)
2.0.0-p247 :001 > first = Email.all[0].datetime
 => Mon, 04 Feb 2013 07:05:28 +0000
2.0.0-p247 :002 > second = Email.all[1].datetime
 => Wed, 21 Aug 2013 11:54:49 +0200
```

The users of my application are located in various timezones, so they each have a database field that states their timezone. This could be e.g. `"+0000"` or `"-0500"`. I need my code to intercept the original timezone and convert the time into the timezone of the user.

E.g.:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :timezone, :type => String, :default => "+0200"
  has_many :emails, :inverse_of => :user
end

class Email
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :datetime, :type => DateTime
  belongs_to :user, :inverse_of => :emails
end


Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.12)
2.0.0-p247 :001 > email = User.first.emails.first
 => #<Email ... >
2.0.0-p247 :002 > datetime = email.datetime
 => Mon, 04 Feb 2013 07:05:28 +0000
2.0.0-p247 :003 > email.update_attribute(datetime: datetime.convert_zone(datetime.zone, user.timezone)  # => convert_zone is not an actual method, so what should I put in here?
 => Mon, 04 Feb 2013 09:05:28 +0200
```

Comment: Why do you need to change the timezone in the db? Wouldn't it suffice to display the time in the user's time zone?

Comment: I calculating a lot of stuff on the basis of the dates, so it's a big advantage to get the conversion done from the beginning.

Comment: Ok then ignore the second half of my answer ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the time zone with ActiveSupport's `in_time_zone` method:

```
email.datetime.in_time_zone(ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new(user.timezone))
```

I would not rely on the datetimes in the db being in the user's timezone as long as this is not a performance issue. For example, what if the user changes his time zone? You would have to recompute the timestamp for all his emails etc. I recommend changing the zone when displaying an email for now.

Comment: Thanks. I can see that it is working when I put in something like `Hawaii` or `Alaska`. Any idea if a list of time zone values exists?

Comment: Apologies. I found it here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html

Comment: This is particularly useful when you are storing the user timezone as Time.zone.name, which is a string, as seen here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html and want to convert it back into an ActiveSupport TimeZone object to do other stuff with it.